# XML via HTTP to send a page with a script

Tags: c#, xml, asp-classic, exception, httpwebrequest

I'm trying send XML document to a page  .asp, and get the answer, but I get following error:

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.     at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)     at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)     at GNS_ZalkarBank.GNSTaskServiceZalkarBank.CreateRequest(String requestData, String address)     at GNS_ZalkarBank.GNSTaskServiceZalkarBank.SendRequest(String requestString, String address)     at GNS_ZalkarBank.GNSTaskServiceZalkarBank.processData(TaskInfo& taskInfo, Object& data)     at Task.RegistryTemplate.RegistryTaskTemplate.execute(DataSet& dataSet)`

I implemented a method for sending data to a page with asp server script:

```
private string SendRequest(String requestString, String address)
{
    address = "https://myadress/osmp_gni_xml.asp";
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = this.CreateRequest(requestString, address);
    string response = GetResponse(httpRequest);
    return response;
}

private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string requestData, string address)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";
    //request.UserAgent = "Test";

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }
    return request;
}

private string GetResponse(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
{
    string responseString;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Server side (script page: osmp_gni_xml.asp):

```
<%@ Language=VBScript CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%    
    Sub AddSubNode(Parent, Name, Value)  
        Set subNode = XMLDoc.createElement(Name)  
        Parent.appendChild(subNode)  
        subNode.appendChild(XMLDoc.createTextNode(Value))  
    End Sub  

    Function Stream_BinaryToString(Binary, CharSet)
        Const adTypeText = 2
        Const adTypeBinary = 1

        'Create Stream object

        Dim BinaryStream 'As New Stream
        Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.

        BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

       'Open the stream And write text/string data To the object

        BinaryStream.Open
        BinaryStream.Write Binary

        'Change stream type To binary

        BinaryStream.Position = 0
        BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText

        'Specify charset For the source text (unicode) data.

        If Len(CharSet) > 0 Then
            BinaryStream.CharSet = CharSet
        Else
            BinaryStream.CharSet = "us-ascii"
        End If

        'Open the stream And get binary data from the object

        Stream_BinaryToString = BinaryStream.ReadText
    End Function

    result=300
    OK="incomplete request"
    Dim PostData
    Dim biData

    PostData = ""
    If Request.TotalBytes>0 Then
        biData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)

        PostData=Stream_BinaryToString(biData, "utf-8")

        ProvStr =  "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=TEST;Initial Catalog=TESTOsmp;User Id=tests_osmp;Password=tests;"

        Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
        Conn.Open ProvStr  
        Set cmdUA = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        cmdUA.ActiveConnection = Conn
        cmdUA.CommandText = "GNI_Import"
        cmdUA.CommandType = 4 
        cmdUA.Parameters.Append cmdUA.CreateParameter("Reestr", 202, 1, 2000, PostData)

        Set RS = cmdUA.Execute
        result = RS("result") 

        RS.Close  
        Conn.Close 
        Set Conn = Nothing  
        Set RS = Nothing 
    End If

    'Create XML  

    Set XMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  

    Set pi = XMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml"," version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""")  
    XMLDoc.appendChild(pi)  

   'Main  

    Set mainNode = XMLDoc.createElement("response")  
    XMLDoc.appendChild(mainNode)  

    If result=0 Then
        OK="Ok"
    Else
        result=300
        OK="incomplete request"
    End If

    AddSubNode mainNode, "result",  result 
    AddSubNode mainNode, "comment", OK
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml"  
    Response.Write XMLDoc.XML  

    Set mainNode = Nothing 
    Set XMLDoc = Nothing   
%>
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided error text comes from here:

```
private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string requestData, string address)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address); // <- THIS LINE
    ...
}
```

The error description is complaining that the address `https://myadress/osmp_gni_xml.asp` is invalid, being `https` the most likely causes are connection issues.

Trying to connect via `https` but not having setup `https` server-side in the first place is very common: verify the address is reachable, security is properly setup, and the sort. A console tool like F12 developer console (part of IE9), FireBug (Firefox extension) or Fiddler (desktop application) are the best tools to find out what's happening when it comes to external connections.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the Problem was the url address. The server uses https - I did not realize. I just asked for a client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the code you've provided isn't the code that has the problem, see this:

```
private string SendRequest(String requestString, --> String address <--)
{
    --> address = "https://myadress/osmp_gni_xml.asp"; <--
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = this.CreateRequest(requestString, address);
    string response = GetResponse(httpRequest);
    return response;
}
```

You're passing address to the method but then hard-wiring it on the first line. The problem's with the format of address, but it probably won't exist with this code.

What may be happening is that you're reading the address from a file or database and as a human you're seeing "https://myadress/osmp_gni_xml.asp" because you're using a flawed unescaping mechanism but what the code is seeing is something like:

```
https/:////myaddress//osmp_gni_xml.asp
```

which gives the same error.

In your actual code, what is the exact value of address in the place where you've overwritten it in SendRequest